# TPS interpolation with validation data points

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, interpolation

I have two set of points. My objective is to perform Thin Plate Spline like interpolation on one set of points and use second set of points to tune the interpolation. Points in first set are uniformly distributed and large in number whereas in second set, are non uniformly distributed and are just a few. In such a case, what should be my optimisation problem? Is there is any other interpolation technique that can be used here? Any reference or clue is appreciated.